# Why is the verb not always put to the end in a subordinate clause?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, adjective, word-order

> Wie sehr sich auch die Verhältnisse in den letzten fünfundzwanzig
>   Jahren geändert haben, die in diesem Manifest entwickelten
>   allgemeinen Grundsätze behalten im Großen und Ganzen auch heute noch
>   ihre volle Richtigkeit.

My teacher taught me that the verb *behalten* should be put to the end of the second part of this sentence, it should be

> die in diesem Manifest entwickelten allgemeinen Grundsaetze im Grossen und Ganzen auch heute noch ihre volle Richtigkeit behalten.

Why is the verb not put to the end in the above quote?

Comment: "behalten" means in this context `they are still valid` or -- not sure whether this is good English `[the basics] keep on being valid [even things have changed]`

Comment: _could_ be translated to this:
Even though the circumstances changed (enormously?) in the last 25 years the general conventions from this manifest keep their overall accuracy.

Comment: @PortreeKid: edits were made by the OP on request to make the question on topic.

Answer (score 4):

### behalten = keep

> Die Grundsätze **behalten** ihre Richtigkeit.
>   The fundamentals **keep** their validity.

Comment: Der OP hat die Frage präzisiert. Jetzt wird nach der Wortstellung gefragt. Vielleicht möchtest du deine Antwort erweitern?

Answer (score 3):

The main statement of the sentence you are quoting is:

> Die in diesem Manifest entwickelten allgemeinen Grundsätze behalten im
>   Großen und Ganzen auch heute noch ihre volle Richtigkeit.

The second part

> Wie sehr sich auch die Verhältnisse in den letzten fünfundzwanzig Jahren geändert haben,

Could be appended to the end or inserted before the main part, without changing meaning (but certainly changing emphasis).

Answer (score 0):

If you use `behalten` in your independent clause, then you can't put the verb to the end.
The conjugated verb in this case is always on first or second position in an independent clause.

> Die, in diesem Manifest entwickelten, allgemeinen Grundsätze **behalten** (second position) im Großen und Ganzen auch heute noch ihre volle Richtigkeit.
>
> Die, in diesem Manifest entwickelten, allgemeinen Grundsätze **haben** (second position) im Großen und Ganzen auch heute noch ihre volle Richtigkeit **behalten**.

The conjugated part of the verb is at the second position in this example.

In a subordinate clause the verb always is at the end of the sentence.

> Ich habe Grundsätze entwickelt, die im Großen und Ganzen auch heute noch ihre volle Richtigkeit **behalten**.

Here is the conjugated part at the end.